# Is there a set of 69 length-6-sets out of 46 numbers [1..46] so that those length-6-sets "cover" all possible 1035 length-2-sets of 46 numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, combinations

1.) For this question, we have 46 numbers (balls, cards, whatever):
{1,2,3,4 .... 45,46}

=======================

2.) 
Each length-6-set of 46 numbers ( e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,6} or {1,13,16,17,32,46 } 'covers' 5+4+3+2+1 = 15 pairs:

E.g. {1,2,3,4,5,6} ==>

(1,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5) (1,6)
(2,3) (2,4) (2,5) (2,6)
(3,4) (3,5) (3,6)
(4,5) (4,6)
(5,6)

===============

3.) 
There are 1035 combinations with length 2 out of 46. ( 46 choose 2 = 1035).

4.) 
There must be one (or more?) combinations of 69 length-6-sets, that contain all possible 1035 pair combinations. Why 69 ? Well, if a length-6-set "covers" 15 pairs, then the number of length-6-sets that we need can be calculated by 1035 / 15 = 69.

Questions:

- Is this set of 69 length-6-sets known?  (where?)
- Have people tried to solve this before?  (what is this problem (or a similar problem) called? How do I find algorithms to solve this?)
- I know a brute force program can solve this, but it would run for a prohibitively long time -- is there an algorithm with a n / n*log n / n^2 ?
- Any other comments welcome :)

My hunch is that this is actually a pretty hard question and that this combination has not been found yet :) (Would also love to be shown a solution)

========================

(This is a lotto-related question. A relative of mine asked me this question and I'd like to give him an answer. I've thought about this for a while now but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: It is not at all obvious (at least to me) that such combinations must exist. It may well be that in order to over all 1035 pairs, some duplication is inevitable.

Comment: What do you mean by you don't believe in lottery systems?

Comment: @Vincent: (About an earlier version of the text; edited since then): I don't believe in "beating" lottery by using systems, it's still random. Let's not discuss this here. (Removed this, as it's not relevant for this question really).

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense. I thought you meant it in a more philosophical way which seemed strange to me.

Comment: @TonyK What you say makes sense. It is not obvious to me either that there is no duplication and we can do it with 69 choices. Then I guess the problem can be reformulated to ask, what would be the minimum number of choices that this can be done.

Comment: Agreed, I wasn't really sure if it can be done in 69 combinations. Not sure how to prove it. But to me it seems plausible. If you have  69 combinations of length 6, you get a matrix of 414 numbers. If you assume that all 46 numbers appear an even number of times in this, it would be 9 times, since 9 *46 = 414. Again, my math skills are not good enough to prove this, that's why I'm here :-)

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is a Steiner (2,6,46) system.  If I further understand [this page](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover/steiner.html) correctly, it is neither known or known not to exist.  This probably means that it is not going to be easy to find.

Comment: @deinst: Thanks a lot for the link -- I will look into this. Small correction of your comment: I think you meant a (46,6,2) system, not (2,6,46).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer is no. For such a situation to exist, every pair of integers in $\{1,\dots,46\}$ would have to be a subset of exactly one of the $69$ $6$-subsets. But if any two of the $6$-subsets were disjoint, then an easy counting argument shows that there would exist two other subsets which intersect in at least two elements. Therefore each pair of $6$-subsets would have to intersect in exactly one element. This is the same as saying that the $69$ subsets form a $(46,6,1)$ [block design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design), which is [known not to exist](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1520-6610(2001)9:1%3C60::AID-JCD5%3E3.0.CO;2-W/abstract).